# Hadoop Mapper Context object

Tags: hadoop

How is the `run()` method of mapper or reducer class called by the Hadoop framework? The framework is calling the `run()` method, but it requires one context object so how is Hadoop passing that object? What information resides in that object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The run() method will be called using the Java Run Time Polymorphism (i.e method overriding). As you can see the line# 569 on the link below, extended mapper/reducer will get instantiated using the Java Reflection APIs. The MapTask class gets the name of extended mapper/reducer from the Job configuration object which the client program would have been configured extended mapper/reducer class using `job.setMapperClass()`

The following is the code taken from the [Hadoop Source MapTask.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/MapTask.java#MapTask.runNewMapper%28org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf,org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable,org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskUmbilicalProtocol,org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.TaskReporter%29)

```
mapperContext = contextConstructor.newInstance(mapper, job, getTaskID(),
                                                  input, output, committer,
                                                  reporter, split);

   input.initialize(split, mapperContext);
   mapper.run(mapperContext);
   input.close();`
```

The line# 621 is an example of run time polymorphism. On this line, the MapTask calls the run() method of configured mapper with 'Mapper Context' as parameter. If the run() is not extended, it calls the run() method on the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper` which again calls the map() method on configured mapper.

On the line# 616 of the above link, MapTask creates the context object with all the details of job configuration, etc. as mentioned by @harpun and then passes onto the run() method on line # 621.

The above explanation holds good for reduce task as well with appropriate ReduceTask class being the main entry class.

Comment: thanks niranjan can u plz explain what all hadoop framework classes are executed while running any simple job??

Comment: It's not a simple answer. There are lot of hadoop framework classes involved which is really whole software layer get executed before the extended classes gets called. I would suggest to download and attach the hadoop sources to your IDE and then debug any job to understand the high level classes used in the call stack.

Comment: @NiranjanSarvi, Could you please tell how MapTask class create an object of other class which is context class ? Is there any relation in between MapTask class and Context class because in library Context class is an abstract class and not even implemented by Maptask class? Is it coming from any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `run()` method of the mapper is called by the MR framework when running the map task attempt. As far as the context is concerned, take a look at the documentation for [Mapper.Context](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.Context.html), especially the implemented interfaces and their javadocs give you a full overview of the information contained in the context. Through the context, you can access data like:

- job information (job configuration, mapper/reducer class names, job name, working directory)
- status of the currently executed task attempt
- current key, value, input split (map task specific information)

Of course similar context object exists for the Reducer: [Reducer.Context](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.Context.html).